# Developing an application against a database with changing schema

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC app which is essentially a web-based reporting tool. The database that I'm pulling from for my reports is still in development, i.e., its schema may change, but if it does, it should change only minimally.

Rather than wait for the database schema to become concrete, I've decided that I can define my data models now as POCOs, and use a repository interface for retrieving data (along with Ninject for IoC). That way, I can build my reporting view-models now using test data, then later, implement my repositories to use the real database, ideally without having to change my model -> view-model mappings.

First question is over terminology: since this is a reporting app, my DB interaction is read-only. Is repository the correct term to use here?

Second question is: is this a decent way to go about this project? If you *had* to create an reporting app where your backing DB schema wasn't concrete, how would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my DB interaction is read-only. Is repository the correct term to use here?

Not really. A repository is essentially a facade operating between your underlying data provider and whatever code is consuming it, exposing all operations that you make available, usually via an interface. It usually wraps the underlying provider (EF, NHibernate, etc) so consuming code has no idea of how the persistence mechanism is implemented.

The fact that you want it "read-only" is an implementation concern. If you don't need to do any writes, i wouldn't even bother with an ORM. It's overkill. Just use stored procedures and if you like, wrap it with a simple component like [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) or [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/). You could then expose these stored procedures via a very simple repository, which just exposes these queries, and nothing else. Just in case you want to switch to something else like classic ADO.NET.

**Using SPROC's have an extra benefit**, you could *fake* the results of the stored procedure. E.g don't make it go to the actual tables, instead fake the result sets in such a way that the result is what you would expect.

Then when the schema is ready, update the SPROC's and your tests should all still pass, assuming you "faked" correctly. Of course if new fields are required, some code may need to change. But using SPROC's here means that your queries will be super-fast (no ORM bloating, close to the metal), and it also helps your scenario here.

I may get attacked by the "stored procedures are prehistoric" followers but that's what i'd do in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. As of right now, I'm using PetaPoco for my wrapper, mainly because I'd like to avoid using dynamics, and use POCOs instead. However, maybe I should consider using Massive w/ dynamics, as it would allow for faster development time.

So, would this be a simple CQRS then, with only read operations? Or should I stick to the repository term? (Or, not bother with using a pattern term, because it's trivial anyway.)

Comment: @mystictheory - i think your getting caught up in lingo. :) Just do what makes sense in your application. It's not CQRS since there are no commands. And it's not really repository since your not really abstracting any kind of data access logic, it's simply a 1-1 wrapper. Anyway, stick with PetaPoco if it works for you. I like strongly-typed goodness too. :)